# d3.js (Tree Layout) - Get Parent node - Strange behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

Some hours that I'm blocked on a problem I can't understand at all.

I've a Tree Layout and if a node has children and has the "subcomponent" attribute, I want to get the parent node. In fact, if the node respects the my two conditions, I want to re-attach it's children to his parent and remove itself.

If I've this scheme :

```
A --> B (subcomponent) --> C
                       --> D
```

I want it to be rendered as follow :

```
A --> C
  --> D
```

To realize that, I've to redefine the children accessor (tree.children) and if the node respects my two conditions, It should transfer his children to his parent and remove himself. To do that, I've the access node parent.

```
tree.children(function children(d) {
    if("children" in d && "subcomponent" in d) {
        console.log(d);
    }

    return d.children;
});
```

The logging statement shows: http://cl.ly/image/3t1n2O1u3U0n so it seems that the parent field exists but I can only access "name", "subcomponent" and "children" keys. Hours and hours I try to access the parent field as it contains all the data I need (for example parent.children field ..)

Here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/LzqNK/1/ The revelant lines are near 29-30 where d is the "Service A.1 node" and where I can to access to "Service A" node as it's its parent node. Once I've the parent node, my entire algorithm to do what I want is already made on my local computer.

Thanks for all.

Comment: It sounds to me like reformatting the data for display (i.e. removing those subcomponents) would be easier.

Comment: It may be but I have to let the possibility to "click" on the node to reveal his subcomponents. I have to be able to switch between the two scheme presented above on a click. That's why I don't want to remove any nodes.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example please?

Comment: Added in main post. :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can do that with the children accessor as it would need to actually modify the tree structure. I would go with two different representations.

Comment: I don't think it does modify the tree structure. Just returning different children depending on a condition. There's no way to access the parent node from a node ? It appears in the console.log(node) but I don't find a way to access the parent field.

Comment: Well the problem is that the parent of the node is only defined after the layout has been run. The children accessor is called during that process, i.e. before the parent has been set.

Comment: Oh ok thanks ! I'll search another solution ...